# Custom Playlists don't play in Apple Music Classical but only in Apple Music?

Tags: apple-music

I have created a custom playlist in Apple Music Classical. When I navigate to it in Apple Music Classical, and tap "Play", it simply doesn't play. Nor does it play when I tap the first piece in the playlist.

Ironically, I can play the playlist just fine in Apple Music! It shows up in my Library, I tap "Play", and it plays just fine.

This seems a bug to me. Has anyone else experienced this?